# Making an aws lambda function available to any caller in any account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Has anyone created a lambda function that is publicly available (without using API gateway)? I'm trying to allow our customers to call the function from their own CloudFormation templates in their own AWS accounts without me knowing their account IDs ahead of time.

I've tried adding permissions to my function with the principal listed as '*' according to this article (https://read.iopipe.com/public-cross-account-functions-on-aws-lambda-bcc148303083), but it doesn't seem to work. I still get a permissions error when calling the function from another account. I've tried several different approaches and still no success.

Hoping someone has done this before and can offer some guidance. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the user (or role) in the other account have permission *in their own user (or role) policy* to invoke the other account's function?  You can't do what you aren't allowed to do, of course, and in cross-account scenarios "allowed" means you need permission from your account as well as from the target account.